# Get visible and not hidden items with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a to take all li elements to array. And ul and li both should be **not** `visibility: hidden` and **not** `display: none`. This is my code.

```
var links = $("li").is(":visible").is(":hidden");
var currentLink = links.first();

alert(currentLink.text());
```

This is my list

```
<ul>
   <li style='display: none'>Coffee</li>
   <li style='visibility: hidden'>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

(I need to show **tea** in alert and not **coffee**)

but I'm getting this error,

> TypeError: $(...).is(...).is is not a function

Comment: `.is(':hidden')` is the the opposite of `.is(':visible')` they conflict like oil and water.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.css("visibility") != "hidden"`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li').each(function(index, item){
        if($(item).css("visibility") != "hidden"){
          console.log($(item).text())
        }
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li').each(function(index, item){
        if($(item).css("visibility") != "hidden"){
          console.log($(item).text())
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>Test visible</li>
<li style="visibility: hidden">Hidden</li>
<li>Test visible2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much it was really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the answers I manage to create a perfect answer. I'm posting it in case if someone in the future may came up with same issue. Thanks so much for everyone helped me.

```
var links = [];
$("li:not(:hidden)").each(function(index, item){
    if($(item).css("visibility") != "hidden"){
       links.push(item); 
    }
});
```